# Why does my cursor select the object in back when I select the top level object in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, layers, workflow

I have two layers in this document, hands on top and orange background behind it.

If I click on the top hand to try to move the layer, I "click through" it and it drags the orange background.
If I click on the lower hand, I can move the layer with the hands.

[Here's a screenshot, showing the Layers panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz4IH.jpg) I cannot share the file itself for copyright reasons.

### Why is this behavior happening?

Comment: You're still able to select the top part of the hand, you can see this at 0.05 seconds. Why it selects the orange background at 0.09 seconds, not sure. You can tell it's going to select the background layer when there is a square dot under your cursor.

Answer (score 1):

`Preferences > Selection & Anchor Display > Command/Ctrl Click To Select Objects Behind`

This pref item gets real confused when using the Command/Ctrl key to temporarily use the Selection Tool. Ai doesn't know if you are Command-Clicking to just use the Selection tool, or Command/Ctrl- Click to select objects behind. And a mistaken double-click almost always resorts to the select behind behavior, if not entering Isolation mode.

Essentially, Adobe has overloaded shortcuts into the Selection Tool and they can often result in undesired behavior. I, personally, disable as many of these as possible most are on by default.

Comment: Adobes way of handling default prefs is horrible. Why do you need to go and immediately change prefs on a clean instal is beyond me.